# React Native Expo - FileSystem readAsStringAsync Byte Allocation Failed (Out of Memory)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am creating an Android App using React Native with Expo Module (FileSystem and Expo AV) to record a local video using the phone's camera, then I send the encoded base64 video to the server.

The code to send the base64 string looks like this:

```
const encodeBase64 = async () => {
  const fileUri = videoUri;
  const options = {
    encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
  };
  let result = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(fileUri, options);

  return result;
};

const upload = async () => {
  const base64 = await encodeBase64(videoUri);
  const result = await myAPI(base64);
}
```

It works on my phone (Oppo A3s), but on another phone like Samsung A51, it gives memory allocation error like this:

[image: Screenshot of error]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is memory error.
Every phone's storage is different each other.
You can use chunk buffer.
So in this case you can split your base64 data to post to server and combine data in server.

ex: client=> chunkbuffer=>1024*100(size)
server=> combine(array of client's data)

Good luck.
If you have any question please contact me.
I will help you anytime.